# Unitary 1x1 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices

In $N > 2$ space there is a type of matrix that is unitary (which has ties to the hilbert space formulation of quantum mechanics). These matrices correspond to a constant rotation from any starting vector. Is there a concept of unitary matrices in a 1 dimensional line?

I know that a 1x1 matrix can be regarded as a scalar.

Comment: No, in higher dimensions a unitary map need not be a rotation. $T$ is unitary if $T^*T=I$. You can use that to determine what the $1\times 1$ unitary matrices are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1×1 matrix is a number, and a unitary such is a phase, $e^{i\phi}$, which, in QM, may multiply wavefunctions without affecting the physics of expectation values.

Acting on infinite lines or circles, it represents the group of translations. You need to provide more context past this.